# Nodejs Electron how to get rid of the right click option on the windows context menu

Tags: node.js, electron

I am trying to get rid of the option to press electron on the windows context menu/rename it and change the picture. To explain it better I want to stop electron showing here https://gyazo.com/8b8f2a17c3ec0acba646a4d4abfacd47

Answer (score 0):

You can't rid of "Electron" context title without building the application.

You need to build your Electron application with electron-builder or electron-packager for Windows.

Answer (score -3):

You can't rid of "Electron" context title without building the application.

You need to build your Electron application with [electron-builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder) or [electron-packager](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager) for Windows.

Comment: You have copied the same answer above